# How do I get a dataframe from python to my files on chrome?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-chrome

I've created a dataframe on python from webscraping and want to use the data on Excel, but everytime I try to add it to my files(I use chromebook) it won't show up.

My original code was:

Input:

```
df.to_csv(r'')
```

and i couldn't figure out the path for my folder I wanted to put it in.
So I tried to figure out the path by adding a file to my new folder to see what path was returned:

Input:

```
import os
pythonfile = 'owid-covid-data.cvs'
print('Absolute path of file:    ', 
    os.path.abspath(pythonfile))
print('Absolute directoryname: ', 
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(pythonfile)))
```

Output:

```
Absolute path of file:    /home/212fb78e-fc5d-482b-82b4-16c1db408898/owid-covid-data.cvs
Absolute directoryname:  /home/212fb78e-fc5d-482b-82b4-16c1db408898
```

Which did not help because it says '/home/212fb78e-fc5d-482b-82b4-16c1db408898' is the path for every file in any folder i pick, it doesnt change.
I even tried adding my data frame to that directory:

Input:

df.to_csv(r'/home/212fb78e-fc5d-482b-82b4-16c1db408898/Companies.csv')

it says it worked no problem, but the file isn't showing up anywhere.

Any help would be awesome, also I am very new to python.

Comment: slightly confused are you using `df.to_csv(r'')` or `df.to_csv(r'owid-covid-data.cvs')`?

Comment: "the file isn't showing up anywhere"  Where are you looking? Try just saving it with `df.to_csv("my.csv")`, then do `os.listdir()` to see if it's there. If it is, you can use `os.getcwd()` to see which directory it's in.

Comment: I just said that as the code I used to try to put it in a folder, I didn't add the path here because I tried multiples with it. it kept saying the folder paths I input were non-existent.  the owid-covid-data.csv is the file I added (not through python) to the folder I need my python dataframe added to, just to see what it said the directory path was to that folder.

Comment: I checked python and it said it was put in my files, just not a certain folder. Then I checked all of my computers files and I cant find it.

Comment: What do you get when you execute `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: "I checked python and it said it was put in my files, just not a certain folder." - What are you checking exactly?

Comment: when I did the 'os.listdir()' it returned '['.virtualenvs',
 '.local',
 '.ipynb_checkpoints',
 '.pythonstartup.py',
 'Companies.csv',
 'Web ScrapingCompanies.csv',
 '.ipython',
 'Untitled.ipynb',
 'README.ipynb',
 '.gitconfig',
 '.vimrc',
 '.cache',
 '.profile',
 'Untitled1.ipynb',
 '.jupyter',
 '.anaconda',
 '.npm',
 '.bashrc']'

Comment: also 'Companies.csv' is the file I am trying to find. and when I did os.getcwd() it returned '/home/212fb78e-fc5d-482b-82b4-16c1db408898' which is its answer for every file I ask where it is located. also sorry, I am not sure how to change my code in my comment to have code format. This is my first time posting on this site.

Comment: I figured it out. I found the file in the file browser on python and opened it in a browser tab and downloaded it to my computer files. Again, I just started using Python a week ago, sorry guys, thanks for all the help though! I really appreciate it.

Comment: `os.getcwd()` doesn't tell you where files are, it tells you your Current Working Directory. It will keep giving you the same answer every time you ask it, until you change directory. If you save a df using only a filename, as in `df.to_csv("my.csv")`, it will save to that directory. Afterwards, you should see it listed when you execute `os.listdir()`